# Diamonds in Mathematical Inequalities,Tran Phuong

Tags: book-recommendation

This book has a bunch of tricks to solve inequalities. So I think I should read this at least once.

But is this book outdated?
There are few data about this.
Is there a way to buy or access this book?

Comment: Outdated? It was written in 2009. There are questions regularly posted on this site about Munkres topology. I studied topology from Munkres in the mid 1980s and it wasn't a new book then. People still study geometry from Euclid, and that is over 2000 years old. Looking over the contents, many of the inequalities date to the 1800s, yet I can tell that just from the names because one encounters these inequalities regularly. No. Is is not outdated. If you are worried it might miss some new result, rest assured that *all* books miss loads of new results.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I don't mind whether the content is old or new but what I am saying is that there are few data about this book on web. I want to read this book.

Comment: @Ris If you are still after "Diamonds in Mathematical Inequalities" there is a version available here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970616/on-the-abstract-concreteness-method-bka-abc-method?noredirect=1#comment8192580_3970616