# On the Abstract Concreteness Method (bka $ABC-$Method).

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

I was reading Zdravko Cvetkovski's excellent book *Inequalities: Theorems, Techniques, and selected problems*, when I arrived at the $16$th chapter: the $ABC-$Method. I had some questions related to this topic, which I could post separately; yet, since they are closely related, I decided to share them at the same time. The first sentence of the section reads

> In this section we will present three theorems without proofs (the proofs can be found in *Diamonds in Mathematical Inequalities (Poung T., $2007$))* which are the basis of a very useful method [...]

This was the first problem: it's almost impossible to find the referenced book — at least, I have failed doing so —. The Mathlinks-user @bitrak claims [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1227738p6201938) that «this book is gift for all contestants on IMO $2007$, [...] in Hanoi-Vietnam.
I don't have this book, because all printed books have only one edition». (**Q0:** Does anybody know if it's possible to get one copy or pdf-version?)

**Q1:** So, I would be very grateful if someone could share the proof of the theorem:

> For this purpose we’ll consider the function $f(abc,ab+bc+ca,a+b+c)$ as a one-variable function with variable $abc$ on $\mathbb R$, i.e. on $\mathbb R^+$.
>
> > **Theorem 16.1** If the function $f(abc,ab+bc+ca,a+b+c)$ is monotonic, then $f$ achieves its maximum and minimum values on $\mathbb R$ when $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=0$, and on $\mathbb R^+$ when $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=0$ or $abc=0$.

> > **Consequence 16.1** Let $f(abc,ab+bc+ca,a+b+c)$ be a linear function with variable $abc$. then $f$ achieves its maximum and minimum values on $\mathbb R$ if and only if $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=0$, and on $\mathbb R^+$ if and only if $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=0$ or $abc=0$.

Also, there are some aspects of this formulation I do not really understand.

**Q2:** First of all, what does the author mean when he states that «we'll consider the function $f(abc,ab+bc+ca,a+b+c)$ as a one-variable function with variable $abc$»? Should I only consider the parts of $f$'s term where $abc$ appears, and think of $ab+bc+ca, a+b+c$ as if they were constant, or are there any further conditions on them? (This question is especially inspired by [this comment](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1227738p6200344) on the previously linked mathlinks-post.)

**Q3:** And what does it mean for $f(abc,ab+bc+ca,a+b+c)$ to be *monotonic* wrt $abc$?

Finally, I noticed that, while Cvetkovski uses «when» in the statement of the Theorem, this becomes «if and only if» in its consequence.

**Q4:** Are they both meant to be «if and only if», or is there a reason for the Theorem to be stated with «when», and the consequence with «if and only if»? If so, what's the reason?

Thanks in advance :)

For more information about the $ABC-$Method, have a look [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1227738). If you know Vietnamese — I don't —, [this](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AI9hcEosit5Y7dY&cid=905BA10DA4AF12DE&id=905BA10DA4AF12DE%21177&parId=905BA10DA4AF12DE%21180&o=OneUp) seems to be the first article published regarding the $ABC-$Method.

**Update:** @Martin Hansen found «[a copy of "Diamonds in Mathematical Inequalities"](http://www.numberwonder.co.uk/Pages/Page0003.html#BMOPreparation) on the number wonder website for pupils preparing for the BMO.» Thanks! It is however unclear, if there was a more developed version...

Comment: +1 same here i used the same book and faced difficulties in understanding this(that part of book remains untouched by me!).... looking forward to an answer..

Comment: There's a copy of "Diamonds in Mathematical Inequalities" on the number wonder website for pupils preparing for the BMO : http://www.numberwonder.co.uk/Pages/Page0003.html#BMOPreparation

Comment: @MartinHansen Thanks! I wonder if this is the complete version, since the introduction refers to about $400$ pages (although the document has $~200$) and many methods described in the preface don’t appear. Anyway, the proof of the ABC-Method seems to be included! I’ll have a closer look when I have time ;)

Comment: @Dr.Mathva It's described at the start as a "proposal for a book". I don't know if there was a more developed version released or if that's as far as it got... I'll keep an ear to the ground for more information (or perhaps someone will pass by here). This book has been asked for before on MSE, (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266318/diamonds-in-mathematical-inequalities-tran-phuong) but without it being tracked down so some progress made today !

Comment: @Dr.Mathva check this out i fpound it helpful file:///home/chronos/u-b09dff150a7f4bdecd284f652a9dcd6fa18ba02d/MyFiles/Downloads/The%20uvw%20method%20(2).pdf

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore thanks! Could you please send the link again; I can’t access it 

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore The attached link is not working, kindly check. It seems to be a useful document, the "uvw" method has been used here, I've seen a few examples.

Comment: Finnally found the correct name of the file it is  'uvw method by Mathias Tejs Knudsen',a free version of pdf is given by Aops